# Maui Bindings don't work unless I make a new Object each time I want to change a property

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, maui

Just getting started with Maui and trying to learn how to properly bind values to a view. I'm having trouble getting bound values to update in the view when the bound data changes, unless I create a new object for each change.
I have a view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:SimultaneousEquations.Models"
             x:Class="SimultaneousEquations.Views.SolveView"
             Title="Solver">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <models:Solver />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Solver"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label FontSize="22" Text="{Binding FirstEquation.AsString}" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label FontSize="22" Text="{Binding SecondEquation.AsString}" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label>
            <Label.FontSize>22</Label.FontSize>
            <Label.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} = {1}">
                    <Binding Path="FirstEquation.FirstVariable" />
                    <Binding Path="FirstValue" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Text>
        </Label>
        <Label>
            <Label.FontSize>22</Label.FontSize>
            <Label.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} = {1}">
                    <Binding Path="FirstEquation.SecondVariable" />
                    <Binding Path="SecondValue" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Text>
        </Label>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" ColumnSpacing="4">
            <Button Text="Solve"
                    Clicked="SolveButton_Clicked" />
        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The views code behind:

```
public partial class SolveView : ContentPage
{
    private Solver solver;

    public SolveView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadEquations();
        BindingContext = solver;
    }

    private void LoadEquations()
    {
        if (BindingContext is Models.Solver)
        {
            solver = new Solver();

            solver.FirstEquation = new Equation();
            solver.SecondEquation = new Equation();

            solver.FirstEquation.FirstVariable = "X";
            solver.FirstEquation.SecondVariable = "Y";
            solver.FirstEquation.FirstCoefficient = 2;
            solver.FirstEquation.SecondCoefficient = -3;
            solver.FirstEquation.Answer = -9;

            solver.SecondEquation.FirstVariable = "X";
            solver.SecondEquation.SecondVariable = "Y";
            solver.SecondEquation.FirstCoefficient = -1;
            solver.SecondEquation.SecondCoefficient = 1;
            solver.SecondEquation.Answer = 2;
        }
    }

    private void SolveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BindingContext is Models.Solver)
        {
            LoadEquations();

            solver.SolveSimultaneousEquations();
            BindingContext = solver;
        }
    }
}
```

A Solver class:

```
internal class Solver
    {
        public Equation FirstEquation { get; set; }

        public Equation SecondEquation { get; set; }

        public float FirstValue { get; set; }

        public float SecondValue { get; set; }

        public void SolveSimultaneousEquations()
        {
            float x =// sums here
            float y =// sums here    
            FirstValue = x;
            SecondValue = y;
        }
    }
```

An Equation class:

```
internal class Equation
    {
        public string FirstVariable { get; set; }

        public string SecondVariable { get; set; }

        public int FirstCoefficient { get; set; }

        public int SecondCoefficient { get; set; }

        public int Answer { get; set; }

        public string AsString { get { return EquationAsString(); }}

        
        private String EquationAsString()
        {
            //stuff here
        }

    }
```

Note in the code behind of the view that LoadEquations() creates a new Solver() and populates its values. These values are displayed in the view on app start up as desired. However, in SolveButton_Clicked I have to call LoadEquations again in order for the Bindings to FirstValue and SecondValue to display. If I only call solver.SolveSimultaneousEquations(); the values of FirstValue and SecondValue in the Solver object get updated but the view does not.
Can anybody explain why this is the case and how I might fix it without creating a new Solver() for each change in the underlying data?

Comment: Basically `Equation` and `Solver` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - otherwise MAUI has no way of being informed that the property has changed. (You could probably explicitly force rebinding, but that wouldn't be very idiomatic.) There may well be a simple framework you can use to make this easier - I'd recommend reading the MAUI binding tutorials, which I'd *expect* to cover this with examples.

Comment: your objects/properties need to be [Observable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject) if you want the UI to dynamically update as they change.

Comment: I've got it working by implementing MVVM and setting my viewModel as ObservableObject, then calling OnPropertyChanged() when I change the variables of note. Thanks for your comments that helped.

Comment: @SteveW You can post your answer as it will help others who have similar issue. If you don't mind, I can help you do that.